# Cross Site Questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, duplicate-questions, cross-posting

I think we should allow for a question to be listed on multiple sites, if it meets the charter of both sites. There would be a feature similar to the "migrate" feature except it will be a "share with other site".

I think there is quite a bit of cross over between this site, [project management](http://pm.stackexchange.com) and [startups](http://startups.stackexchange.com). It will be beneficial to both site to cross list questions with one set of answers, of course.

Comments?

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing wrong with posting the same question on multiple sites - **as long as it's tailored for each site and not a cut and paste repost**.

Each site is unique. It has it's own community and own guidelines for what is on and off topic. It would be a very rare question indeed that was on topic on more than one site *if posted without modification for that site*.

Additionally the fact that you think the question might be suitable for multiple sites could be an indication that the question is too broad - you should narrow it to something more specific. In this case you might well find that what you have is several related questions some of which are on topic here, others which are on topic on other sites.

Comment: Coming from [this discussion](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5654/are-you-still-confused-about-what-programmers-is-for). Each site being it's own "precisely defined" expert community, is just pretending that in real life you can focus on playing in your own sand-box and not be influenced by what's around you. That's wishful thinking, overlap is inevitable.

Comment: @RafaelCichocki - I'm not saying that there isn't overlap, but where there is you should tailoring your question.

Comment: I agree that it's good to try to define distinction, which is a community process(users + moderators). But when I need help, I get angry, because I'm used to getting good answers on StackExchange, but lately I'm just seeing lots of "Your question is not interesting to this community (... go [hug] yourself)."

Comment: @RafaelCichocki - I think that's a separate issue and perhaps one that deserves it's own meta question.