# Do we allow cross posting from non-tech SEs?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

Take for example [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151157/what-is-the-equivalent-word-for-compile-in-an-interpreted-language).  This user knows they are cross posting and the question is word for word the same as the one on english.se.  I wanted to say something, but I figured someone else would have already since he admits to cross posting.  Is this allowed? The consensus seems to be the same on both sites.

Comment: It's OT on EL&U: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/1088/1696

Answer (score 7):

Cross posting is not to be encouraged.

The same question can be asked on multiple sites, but it should be tailored to each site's audience. It's the rare question that can be asked "as is" on multiple sites.

The problem here is that the OP was encouraged to ask by comments such as this:

[This should be posted to StackOverflow or Programmers.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69549/what-is-the-equivalent-word-for-compile-in-an-interpreted-language#comment134149_69549)

The correct approach should have been for the users on English to flag the post for moderator attention so that it could be migrated.

I see that it's now got identical answers on both sites - hardly useful.

Answer (score 5):

I think the question should have been migrated instead of cross-posted, but that said, cross-posting is discouraged but not against the rules

Per [this answer by ChrisF](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2105/1130)

> There's nothing wrong with posting the same question on multiple sites
>   - **as long as it's tailored for each site and not a cut and paste repost**.
>
> Each site is unique. It has it's own community and own guidelines for
>   what is on and off topic. It would be a very rare question indeed that
>   was on topic on more than one site *if posted without modification for
>   that site*.

The answer given by one site could be different than the answer given by another site. For example, an English professor might give a different answer to that question than a programmer would. In addition, I wouldn't expect an English professor to know programming terms.

Comment: I find it interesting how you manage to gather down votes on meta so easily, even when you say the exact same thing as up voted answers.

Comment: @Ryathal lol glad to know I'm not the only one who thinks so :)

Comment: -1 for saying exact same thing as up voted answers.

Comment: @psr Actually if you look at the time these were both posted, mine was posted 4 seconds after Chris' answer, so I did not see any other answer when I posted this one. I left my answer after noticing Chris had posted one too because it contains some information that his answer does not, such as a link to a similar question, and I prefer my answer to his. But thank you for explaining your downvote :)

Comment: I didn't really downvote.  Ryathal's comment just made me think of some of the, um, idiosyncratic reasons people sometimes have for their votes.

Comment: @psr Thanks, but I've accepted the fact that some people just don't like me and are much more likely to downvote (or not upvote) things I say, regardless of what they are or what logic is presented ;) Ryathal's comment was made a few hours after these were posted, when my answer had -1, and Chris' had +3, which really made no sense since they both say the same thing and were posted at the same time. You can see the full timeline of the question [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/3644/timeline)